# UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: message.author.displayAvatarURL is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

Pretty simple error here but I have no idea why this wouldn't work.

The official documentation on the User class says that displayAvatarURL is a valid function for it.
However, I get the error specified in the title when I run the following code.
`console.log(message.author.displayAvatarURL());`

My first thought is that maybe message.author isn't actually the user class but I run the following line of code in the same part of the program and it runs fine.
`console.log(message.author.defaultAvatarURL);`

Anyone know what's going on here?

Comment: What version of discord.js are you using?

Comment: discord.js@11.5.1

Comment: I updated discord.js to the latest version (12.2.0 at this time of writing) and it seems to have fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

`defaultAvatarUrl` is a property and `displayAvatarURL()` is a method in User class.

Probably the `message.author` in the first case is not an instance of the User class.

Comment: Is that normal? I would think that message.author would be a specific instance of a user given what it is. ```console.log(message.author.username)``` prints the username of the author correctly as well.

Comment: It can happen when you, for example, do a deepClone of the object, or something like `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(object))`. Hard to say.
Try to `console.log(message.author)` in the first case and check if it has this method inside

Comment: @TomaszJaniszewski This seems more like a comment than an answer, please keep it in the comments unless it's an actual answer.

Comment: I would love to, but I cannot comment yet... :(

Comment: @TomaszJaniszewski I figured this might be the problem, but even in the following code, I still get the same error.


`client.on('message', async message => {
 console.log(message.author.displayAvatarURL());
}`

I cannot seem to get it to display the method when simply printing message.author.

Comment: Ok, if you using 11.5.1 then there is no such a method so that might be the issue :) https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/11.5.1/class/User

Answer (score 0):

Use [`message.author.avatarURL()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/User?scrollTo=avatarURL) instead of [`message.author.displayAvatarURL()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/User?scrollTo=displayAvatarURL)

Comment: I still run into the same issue. Through further testing, it looks like none of the methods attached to the user class work, while all of the properties do.

Comment: What's your node.js version?

Comment: Node.js version is v12.16.0